# How to set django model field value based-on value of other field in the same Model

Tags: python, django

I want to assign a `NullBooleanField` value to always oppose other field value in the same model, except for `None`. From models below, i want to make sure if the value of `scam` is `True`, the value of `whitelist` can not also be `True`. But if `scam` is `None`, `whitelist` allowed to also set to `None`. The expected criteria is one of the followings:

1. If `scam` is `True`, the allowed value of `whitelist` is `False` or `None`
2. If `scam` is `False`, the allowed value of `whitelist` is `True` or `None`
3. If `scam` is `None`, the allowed value of `whitelist` is `True` or `False` or `None`

So, how to make sure `scam` is always the opposite of `whitelist`?

This is my class model:

```
class ExtendHomepage(models.Model):
    "extending homepage model to add more field"
    homepage = models.OneToOneField(Homepage)

    # True if the website is a scam, False if not, None if not sure
    scam = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    # True if the webpage is already inspected, False if not 
    inspected = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # True if the website is already reported, False if not yet 
    reported =  models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    # True if the website response is 200, else it is False
    access =  models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # True if the web should be whitelist, False if should not, None pending
    whitelist =  models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your criteria, but you can use validation:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.scam and self.whitelist:
        raise ValidationError("Can't set whitelist and scam simultaneously.")
    if self.scam is False and self.whitelist is False:
        raise ValidationError("Negate either whitelist or scam or none.")
```

Update your question with a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) so we can understand what you want.

Comment: I decided to use clean() & and overwrite save(). clean() to validate form input when editing existing data, and custom save() to automatically assign value when inserting new known scam website. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a **property** getter and setter for this necessity similar below code:

```
class ExtendHomepage(models.Model):
    "extending homepage model to add more field"
    homepage = models.OneToOneField(Homepage)

    # True if the website is a scam, False if not, None if not sure
    scam = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    # True if the webpage is already inspected, False if not 
    inspected = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # True if the website is already reported, False if not yet 
    reported =  models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    # True if the website response is 200, else it is False
    access =  models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # True if the web should be whitelist, False if should not, None pending

    __whitelist = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def whitelist(self):
        if self.scam is not None and self.scam == self.__whitelist:
            # this if block is not necessary but for 
            # check if content changed directly in database manager
            # then assign None value to this attribute
            self.__whitelist = None
        return self.__whitelist

    @whitelist.setter
    def whitelist(self, value):
        self.__whitelist = value
        if self.scam is not None and self.scam == self.__whitelist:
            self.__whitelist = None
```